# Not able to click on drop down menu

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I have 4 drop down menu in my application and when we click on any drop down then selection list appears. So I am able to click on first drop down and can select any value from list.

**My Issue  : I am not able to click on 2nd drop down to choose value.**

Xpaths used for 1st and 2nd drop down-

```
1. ProcessName_xpath=//span[contains (text(),'Process Name :')]

2. ProcessStatus_xpath=//span[contains (text(),'Status :')]
```

if I remove 1st click step from my test cases then status xpath works fine.

When used both steps, 2nd step is failing. Why?

Error:

> Unable to locate element

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: what is the exception you are getting? also, why are you not selecting dropdown by creating the `Select` object

Comment: I have attached the code screenshot.

Comment: what is exception you are getting. your answer would be in the error

Comment: unable to locate element

Comment: In which language you are automating your selenium script? Provide proper tag along with question. and Instead of providing `image`, please provide an `html` code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use explicit wait until the element is present. I am not sure which programming language you are using, so following code is in python

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains (text(),'Status :')]")))
```